# A combinatorial problem

Tags: linear-algebra, extremal-combinatorics

What is the largest $m\times m$ $0/1$ matrix of real rank $n$ with every square submatrix sized at least ${n^{\gamma}}\times{n^{\gamma}}$ distinct for some fixed $\gamma>0$?

**Upper Bounds:** Number of ways to choose $n^\gamma$ rows and columns is $\binom{m}{n^\gamma}^2\approx2^{2n^\gamma\log m}$ which needs to be less than total number of $0/1$ $n^\gamma\times n^\gamma$ matrices which is $2^{n^{2\gamma}}$ which gives $2\log m<n^\gamma$ which is approximately $m<2^{n^\gamma}$.

Is the trivial asymptotic upper bound $2^{n^\gamma}\times2^{n^\gamma}$ achievable (I am only interested in asymptoticc results)?

I think it is achievable if $0<\gamma<\frac12$ holds. Could there be a construction or a proof?

Else we saturate at $\gamma=\frac12$ with largest such matrix peaking at $2^{\sqrt n}\times2^{\sqrt n}$ asympotically.

Comment: whoever downvoted what is unclear?

Comment: The question at present reads fine to me, but note that this is your fourth  attempt at formulating this (in under one hour), and perhaps you could have put in the effort to formulate the question carefully before posting.  I can't know of course, but that may have influenced the down vote/close vote.

Comment: @Lucia no the person downvoted on first attempt and I tried to change after that

Comment: Yes, I think that's Lucia's point.

Comment: So, you are interested in logarithmic asymptotics and $2^{n^\gamma}$ and $2^{n^\gamma/2}$ are less or more the same for you? This should be specified in the question.

Comment: @FedorPetrov updated posting.